# text dimension in beamer

Tags: beamer, minipage, columns, width

I can't understand how to dimension minipages or columns in a beamer frame.

Creating a single column with width `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` (or 2 columns with width `0.5 \textwidth` or `0.5\linewidth`) causes horizontal overful as you can see in the picture where frame boundaries have been highlighted

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\justifying
\lipsum[75]

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}
mp1
\end{minipage}} 
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
mp2
\end{minipage}} 

\begin{columns}
\fbox{
\begin{column}{1\textwidth}
c1
\end{column}}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
\fbox{
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
c1
\end{column}}
\fbox{
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
c2
\end{column}}
\end{columns}


\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
mp1
\end{minipage}} 
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
mp2
\end{minipage}}


\end{frame} % 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The good news is: it seems, as if you did set up your `column`s and your `minipage`s correct.

The bad new is: you didn't take care of suppressing unwanted white spaces and you forgot that the fbox always adds a small gap between the box and its frame.

To prevent the unwanted white spaces, you should use the comment character (`%`) frequently (at the important places, especially line ends!).

To prevent the gap between the box and its frame, just set the dimen `\fboxsep`to be `0pt`.  This works rather well, but in case, you put a fbox next to another fbox, you'll have to take the linewidth of the frames into account.  I added an example at the end of my MWE, to show the effect and how to prevent it.

In case of the `column`s: Placing the `\fbox` at the correct place in the code seems to be important.  You have to frame the `column`-environment, not a single `columns`.

Here is my enhanced MWE of yours:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


%% Set the gap between the box and its frame to be exactly 0pt
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[75]

\fbox{% <--- There was a blank space inserted between the surrounding
      % box and the minipage.  See next example
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}
    mp1
  \end{minipage}} 
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
mp2 with leading blank space
\end{minipage}} 

%% Next test: Beamer-Columns  It seems, as if the location of the
%% \fbox is important  This example works
\fbox{\begin{columns}%
  \begin{column}{1\textwidth}
    \centering c1 (everthing fine!)
  \end{column}%
\end{columns}}
\begin{columns}%
  \fbox{\begin{column}{1\textwidth}
    \centering c2 (incorrect!)
  \end{column}}%
\end{columns}

%% Same problem with two columns.
\fbox{\begin{columns}%
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering c3.1 (fine!) 
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering c3.2 (also fine!)
    \end{column}%
  \end{columns}}
\begin{columns}%
    \fbox{\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering c4.1 (not fine!) 
    \end{column}}%
    \fbox{\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering c4.2 (neither fine!)
    \end{column}}%
  \end{columns}


%% This box is too full, because of four thin vertical lines.
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
mp1
\end{minipage}}% <--- blank space!
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
mp2
\end{minipage}}

%% Same again, this time adjustet by the line thickness.  Define a new
%% length, set it to half the textwidth and add "- 2 rulewidth" to it
%% (that is, removing them from the length)
\newlength{\halfline}
\setlength{\halfline}{0.5\textwidth}
\addtolength{\halfline}{-2\fboxrule}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\halfline}
    New MP2
  \end{minipage}}%
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\halfline}
    New MP2
  \end{minipage}}%
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]